# How to prevent multiple login prompt in sharepoint for multiple web application

Tags: sharepoint-server

Currently, We are getting the credential prompt for each web applications when user accessing from out side network. our SharePoint web application is open in internet but when any user accessing from outside our domain he is getting prompt for each web application.is there any mechanism that will allow me one login in one browser an din same browser I can access other web application without prompt. example google if we login to google they we no need to login again for youtube, drive and other google product. we want only one authentication prompt to authenticate multiple web application.

below is multiple web application in same farm.

Web application  - xxx.xxxxxx.com
Web application  - yyy.xxxxxx.com
Web application   - zzz.xxxxxx.com

It asks credential three times. but my requirement is that It should prompt for credential only once and will forward authorization for other application if it opens in same browser in multiple tab.

Comment: You need to configure ADFS with single sign on in your SharePoint to authenticate other web applications. Different web applications always asks for authentication though you use them in your domain. But it sometimes happens if your browser is set to automatic authentication with current user for intranet zone.

Comment: Hello Dikesh, Our all users are not in our domain. Some are accessing from other workgroup. This is happening only for users who are accessing outside of our network. One more point ADFS is not a solution as other users are not in any domain they are random user. also from those three web application one is claim based and two is classic also it have integration with OOS 2016.

Answer (score 0):

As you obviously use a reverse proxy configured with "pass-through" SharePoint gets the request and asks for credentials. SharePoint does not remember your credentials for other web applications and will ask for every web application for credentials.

Solution is to configure the reverse proxy for "pre-authenticate". This is just possible if you connect it to an adfs server to do credential checking.

Reverse proxies that are able to do "pre authentication" are:

- Microsoft Web Application Proxy (recommended by Microsoft)
- Kemp Loadmaster (at least 2000 and 5000 works fine, I am sure others can do as well)

There are more products on the market I think. This two do a fine job when configured right as we used both.

Comment: Our all users are not in our domain. Some are accessing from other workgroup. This is happening only for users who are accessing outside of our network. One more point ADFS is not a solution as other users are not in any domain they are random user. also from those three web application one is claim based and two is classic also it have integration with OOS 2016.